# Laravel returning HttpException object instead of showing custom error pages

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5

I'm using spatie permissions module for controlling roles and permissions within my site. I have added a bit to the Authenticate middleware. My Handle now looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest())
    {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);

        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }

    if ( ! Auth::user()->can('access acp') )
    {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
            return response('Unauthorised.', 403);

        abort(403, "You do not have permission to access the Admin Control Panel. If you believe this is an error please contact the admin who set your account up for you.");
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So if the user isn't logged in we send them to the login page, otherwise we check if the have permissions to access the acp, and if not show them a 403 error. I've added a 403.blade.php to the views/errors folder. However when I run that code I just get a Whoops! and the developer tools show a 500 ISE is being returned. I don't understand why I'm not seeing my custom error page.

So far I've tried switching the environment to production and turning debug mode off but that doesn't show the page. I've also tried throwing an authorisation exception but that doesn't do anything different. I also tried using `App::abort()` but again, I still got the 500 ISE.

I've tried Googling the issue but I can't find anyone else having this issue. I would really appreciate any help in getting this working.

Whoops returns

[image: Error output]

If I modify the code thusly

```
try
{
    abort(403, "You do not have permission to access the Admin Control Panel. If you believe this is an error please contact the admin who set your account up for you.");
} catch ( HttpException $e )
{
    dd($e);
}
```

then I get an instance of `HttpException` with my error code and message, so why isn't that then showing a custom error page?

Comment: What exception message are you seeing on your 500?

Comment: It's showing me the message I'm passing to the abort, `You do not have permission to access the Admin Control Panel. If you believe this is an error please contact the admin who set your account up for you.`

Comment: Did you check your PHP error log? 500 indicates that we're talking about a higher-level error.

Comment: Although the developer tools say it's a 500 I'm not sure it is, I just think it's returning an incorrect code. There is no log file, not sure why not. I'm running on Xampp with PHP7 but the logs folder is empty.

Comment: Install xdebug and set some breakpoints, its unlikely anyone remote can help debug this

Comment: @Steve the code looks to be running properly, I've looked in xdebug and everything seems to run as it should. The only problem is it doesn't show a custom error page as the documentation says it will. I've updated my question to clarify this and would appreciate it if you could have a look.

Comment: How about the `App/Exceptions/Handler` class? Follow the xdebug steps to see if it reaches the `render` method and what happens next

Comment: What environment is Laravel set to? Is `debug` set to `true` in `app/config/app.php`? Try setting it to false if so and try again.

Comment: @Jamesking56 It's set to `local` and `debug` is set to `true`, I have already tried setting it to `production` and `false` but I just get the standard whoops page with no debugging info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to get around this problem with the the code below (note that it is a Lumen app but it should work with Laravel)

> routes.php

```
$app->get('/test', function () use ($app) {
    abort(403, 'some string from abort');
});
```

> resources/views/errors/403.blade.php

```
<html>
    <body>
    {{$msg}}
    <br>
    {{$code}}
    </body>
</html>
```

> app/Exceptions/Handler.php, modify render() function as below

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();

        if (view()->exists('errors.'.$statusCode)) {
            return response(view('errors.'.$statusCode, [
                'msg' => $e->getMessage(), 
                'code' => $statusCode
            ]), $statusCode);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

It does what the Laravel should do according to docs

Comment: Thank you! That did it. That was such a pain in the ass. I'm guessing I overwrote what was originally there when I put in Whoops.